# How do you parse FASTA file and submit sequence to SQLite db file in Perl using DBI?

Tags: database, perl, sqlite, dbi

I have a FASTA file as follows

```
>header1
AAAAA
AAA
>header2
BBBBB
```

I've been able to create a SQLite table via perl using DBI.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:SQLite:dbname=gene.db" , "" , "" ,
                    { PrintError => 0 , RaiseError => 1 } );
$dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS genes");
$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE genes(gene_name VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, sequence TEXT)");

parse();
sub parse{
my $fasta_file = 'example.faa';
my $header='';
my $sequence='';

open(INPUT, $test_file) || die "ERROR: can't read input file: $!";
    while(<INPUT>){
        if(/^>(.+?)/){
           $header=$1;
          #$dbh->do("INSERT INTO genes VALUES('$header','$sequence')");
           $sequence='';
        }else{
           $sequence.=$_;
        }
     }
}
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Now I know `$dbh->do("INSERT INTO genes VALUES('$header','$sequence')");` will insert the header and sequence into the database, but I'm having issues with the first entry, especially if the first entry has a multiple line sequence. The sequence for the first entry seems to be shifted down to the second. I've tried to move the `$dbh->do` statement into else, but I can an error. Thoughts?

```
sqlite> select * from Genes;
header      sequence
----------  ----------  
header1      
header2     AAAAAAAA
```

I get the following error if I put the `do()` statement in the `else` clause.

```
DBD::SQLite::db do failed: column header is not unique
```

Comment: define "issues". do you get an error message?

Comment: @Cfreak Sorry, I submitted the question before fully explaining. I get the following error: DBD::SQLite::db do failed: column header is not unique

Answer (score 0):

The first entry has no value for $sequence, so I'd refactor your code in this way:

```
if(/^>(.+?)/) {
   $header=$1;

} else{
   $sequence = $_;
   $dbh->do("INSERT INTO genes VALUES(?, ?)", undef, $header, $sequence );  
}
```

Note the $dbh->do syntax, this mode avoid the sql injection problems

Comment: I still get the following error: DBD::SQLite::db do failed: column header is not unique. Any ideas?

Comment: your column header at genes table is defined as UNIQUE (or PRIMARY KEY), so try to remove this constraint at SQLite database

Comment: Doing that adds a double entry (2 header1 entries):

    header      sequence
    ----------  ----------  
    header1     AAAAA 
    header1     AAAAAAAA
    header2     BBBBB

Answer (score 0):

The order of your statements in the while loop are out of order I think. And you need to add a `chomp` to delete the new lines (unless you intend to keep them).

```
open(INPUT, $test_file) || die "ERROR: can't read input file: $!";
    while(<INPUT>){
        chomp;
        if(/^>(.+)/){
            $dbh->do("INSERT INTO genes VALUES('$header','$sequence')") if $sequence;
            $header=$1;
            $sequence='';
        }else{
           $sequence.=$_;
        }
     }
     $dbh->do("INSERT INTO genes VALUES('$header','$sequence')") if $sequence;

         }
```

**Update:** Added last $dbh->do after the while loop to get the last record.